# como puedo eliminar caracteres de este JSON en postman o javascript

Tags: javascript, json

tengo el siguiente JSON en postman,

```
bodyRequest =  "{\r\n    \"idempotentReference\": \"1234567\",\r\n    \"destinationName\": \"prueba\",\r\n    \"fxValueDetailsNominal\": {\r\n        \"paymentAmount\": {\r\n            \"currency\": \"USD\",\r\n            \"amount\": 100.00000\r\n        }\r\n    }\r\n}"

trato de quitarle los caracteres \r \n, las diagonales invertidas, y los espacios que estan antes de estas "    \" o " \"
```

realizo un bodyRequest.replace("\r\n", '') y bodyRequest.replace("    \", '')

pero solo me elimina los primeros, como puedo eliminar el resto y dejar el json limpio, como asi:

```
{"idempotentReference":"1234567","fxValueDetailsNominal":{"paymentAmount":{"amount":100.000,"currency":"USD"}},"destinationName":"prueba"}
```

o si hay alguna expresión regular con la que pueda limpiar todo esto?

PD:
este body lo tomo desde el postman pre request, y al imprimirlo por consola, me aparece con esos caracteres, hay alguna forma de evitar que salga con eso? pero manteniendo los valores numericos?, por ej: Tengo otro en el cual recibo el body como body = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw), luego a este body le hago un json.stringify(body), pero este ultimo al imprimirlo el valor numerico me queda en 100 y no como corresponde que seria 100.000; hasta el momento lo unico que me ha servido es de la otra forma, sin hacer un JSON.parse()

Comment: ¿Cómo generas el valor en ese `bodyRequest` ?

Comment: pm.request.body.raw, y después hago un JSON.stringify(bodyRequest)

Comment: incluye esa información en tu pregunta, potencialmente el problema podría estar en la forma en que lo generas y no en la forma de reemplazar los caracteres.

Comment: `JSON.stringify() ` no retorna cosas como `\r\n`, probablemente lo estés copiando de la ventana de postman que tiene una especie de "embellecedor" que le agrega eso para que se vea mejor.

Comment: exacto, lo tomo desde el postman pre request, y al imprimirlo por consola, me aparece con esos caracteres, hay alguna forma de evitar que salga con eso? pero manteniendo los valores numericos?, por ej:

Tengo otro en el cual recibo el body como body = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw),
luego a este body le hago un json.stringify(body),

pero este ultimo al imprimirlo el valor numerico me queda en 100 y no como corresponde que seria 100.000; hasta el momento lo unico que me ha servido es de la otra forma, sin hacer un JSON.parse()

Comment: \ es un carácter de escape. Solo lo ves cuando escribes un literal. Imprimelo en consola y verás que "desapareció".

Comment: Dado que \ es un carácter de escape, para eliminarlo debes "escapar" dicho carácter. El segundo replace debe ser  `bodyRequest.replace(" \\", '')` (con dos barras invertidas seguidas)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes eliminarlos usando lo siguiente:

```
bodyRequest.replace(/\r\n/g,"")
```

Esto elimina todos los "\n" y "\r".

[Más información sobre Expresiones Regulares (regex)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)